# Will journals care if I post a "collected works" on my homepage?

Tags: publications, journals, copyright

I am considering posting a "collected works" which incorporates all of my papers (up to this point) on a particular subject. This way, someone new to my work can get it all in one document. I plan to update it as I do more research.

It is not intended for publication (and will never be submitted for publication).

Much of the content will be copy/paste from papers which have been published. I'm thinking something like one chapter for each paper. My formatting will be generic; I'm not grabbing screenshots of the published edition or anything like that.

Is this typically something that would be allowed?  Does the content of my papers belong to me, so long as I do not try to publish it elsewhere?

Comment: I don’t understand the point - people will want your actual papers so they can cite them, not a huge file of everything. Have a list of publications, with links to the journal/DOI. Done.

Comment: @JonCuster Because I can add context, re-organize and assimilate the content.  Same reason we have textbooks.

Comment: People will want your actual publications.  They do not want this.

Comment: I agree with the others commenting. It sounds like what you want to do is write commentaries (in the Greek classics sense) on the papers, and this is fine, but people interested in citing specific results in specific papers will want the actual unaltered published versions (or links to them; or at least an accurate bibliographic citation), not your commentaries. However, such commentaries would probably be useful to anyone interested in updates (and this includes stuff other people might have done) on research related to your work. **(continued)**

Comment: For a rather marginally related example, see [this web page](http://mathjeecommentary.blogspot.com/), which near the top says: *My book Educative JEE (Mathematics) covers nearly all problems in Mathematics at the Joint Entrance Examination (JEE) upto the year 2002. To supplement this book, I have been writing educative commentaries on the JEE Mathematics papers from 2003 onwards.* Those commentaries are posted at this web page. Incidentally, I've never previously heard of the [JEE tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination), although I probably should have.

Comment: Maybe nobody wants it, but that is really beside the point.  My question is asking whether it would be allowed.

Comment: Unless I'm missing the point, the issue of whether it is allowed will depend on the various publishing agreements between you and the publishers of your papers.